# Android Studio: distances shown on layout preview appear larger on device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm currently learning Android Development following a book and using Android Studio to do the creating and a Nexus 4 device for testing. I've been using the layout previewer to test my layout for whether it's good to go or not.

Here is a screenshot of the layout and how it appears in the Android Studio previewer. Sorry for the large size.

[image]

Here is a screenshot taken from my Nexus 4 device to show the differences.

[image]

As you can see the EditText fields are showing as in line on the preview but out of line on the device. I compared the 2 images and the rest of the elements are in place as they should be, except for the EditTexts. The layout is using 2 nested LinearLayout one left one right.

Here's how one of my EditText's are defined in the XML. All the others are copies of this with different IDs.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/editTextColonies"
          android:inputType="number"
          android:ems="12"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="12dp"/>
```

I'm wondering if this is caused by my code, my device or simple the Android Studio.
Thanks in advance for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to a RelativeLayout if you can, you can then define android:layout_toRightOf and android:layout_below XML tags. I don't recommend using the GUI to place objects with RelativeLayout as it is quite annoying. It's easier to just place it with XML.

Comment: Thank you, I adapted to a RelativeLayout and set it up that way with align the baseline and parent to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Make rows of Buttons next to EditTexts. Each row should be a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout, and you should set the android:height="wrap_content" for each of those rows. Put your button edittext pairs into each of those.

```
<LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom" >

         <Button
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/button_name_colonists"
           android:id="@+id/colonistsButton"/>

         <EditText android:id="@+id/editTextColonists"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="12"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Something to look at for re-using layouts such as the commonly repeated rows is [this link by Google about include.](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for this, but in the end I decided to go with a RelativeLayout.